# Is there any global web usage statistics feed?

Tags: xml, json, google-analytics, statistics

G'day,

I've been unsuccessfully looking for global web statistics raw data feeds (browsers, OS, screen resolution, etc) - in xml or json (or else) format.

I'd happy with the data offered by W3C or W3Counter.

Ideally I'd like to compare & graph several data source

In the same spirit, is it possible to query Google Analytics for global data? And how?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Google does not offer such reports. You can get your data in parseable format by grabbing the wiki markup from Wikipedia pages such as these:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_operating_systems